# How to make cumulative search with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search, linq-to-sql

If i want to search by `req_ser ,req_year .. ,so on fields`

I do the following :

```
            if (obj.RequestSerial != 0)
            {
                if (condition != "")
                    condition = condition + " AND ";

                condition += " req_ser= " + obj.RequestSerial;
            }

            if (obj.RequestYear != 0)
            {
                if (condition != "")
                    condition = condition + " AND ";

                condition += " req_year = " + obj.RequestYear;
            }
```

then in my select statement i do the following :

```
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ..... + condition
```

---

How to search using the same concept with LINQ TO SQL entities ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the same logic...

```
var query = DB.MyItems;

if(conditionA != 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.A == conditionA);

if(conditionB != 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.B == conditionB);

var items = query.ToList();
```

---

using the properties in your question, your code may look like this:

```
var query = DB.MyItems;//I don't know what you table it called

if(obj.RequestSerial != 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.req_ser == obj.RequestSerial);

if(obj.RequestYear != 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.req_year== obj.RequestYear);

var items = query.ToList();
```

Comment: then in my `select linq statement` ?

Comment: @just_name: Don't use a select statement like that. Or Don't apply the where on the statement and then use the `Where` functions like I said.

Comment: Did these statements make the cumulative search that i want ?

Comment: To do the select, you would do `var items = query.Select(x => x.valueYouWant);` or `var items = query.Select(x => new { ValueA = x.valueYouWantA, ValueB = x.valueYouWantB, etc. });`  possibly with a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end if necessary.

Comment: @just_name: I have updated my answer to include who it might look with your specific properties